# When to switch to new zoom-level using deepZoom

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, deepzoom

I am trying to write an renderer for a very large image, and I've generated a set of image tiles using DeepZoom, with an overlap of 2 and a tilesize of 1024 (original image is 16200x8100).

Currently, my renderer switches to the next zoom level when the scale-transformation doubles, or switches out to when it halves. However, when the next zoom-level is switched to, the camera is offset by some pixels to the left (even if the offset transform has not changed), as though the images are bigger. How can I compensate for this or is there some particular time at which I should switch to the next zoom level?

Comment: Are you properly overlapping the tiles? If not, that would account for the shifting. BTW, here's some info on the format if it's helpful: https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/wiki/The-DZI-File-Format Also, I'd love to know why you're building your own renderer instead of using OpenSeadragon… just curious :-)

Comment: @iangilman In what way should I overlap the tiles? I read something about a power of two there (I've read that info before)? Currently I'm generating tiles with no overlap at all. as it's only the bottom row and far right column of tiles that are not a size contiguous with all other cells. I'm drawing the tiles just like 'col * tilesize, row * tilesize', of course these coordinates are scaled based on the canvas context.
I'm building my own renderer as part of a project as I'm actually developing a piece of mapping software that I don't really want to have to build on top of OpenSeadragon.

Comment: In your original comment you said you had an overlap of 2, and now you're saying you have no overlap. Does that mean you tried it with an overlap of 2 and with no overlap and you get the same behavior either way? If so, then that does away with my overlap theory.